# How to suppress Cannot Find Symbol error when compiling java?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room, android-databinding, dagger

I'm using Dagger, Room and DataBinding to develop my application, these libraries generate massive codes. When something wrong happened in my code, these libraries stop generating codes and produce massive Cannot Find Symbol error, which is annoying.

And java compiler will only output first 100 errors, which makes situation worse, I can't even knows where is the error of my code! Because all errors are 'Cannot Find Symbol'.

Is there anyway to suppress these Cannot Find Symbol errors, or, at least, shows dagger or databinding errors before these errors?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase *Error Limit*.

Just include below lines in your grade

### Java

```
allprojects{
  afterEvaluate{
     tasks.withType(JavaCompile.class) {
       options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500"
     }
   }
 }
```

### Kotlin

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I don't think this is a real solution.